# SSMS object explorer options when connected to Azure database

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I recently installed Sql2012.  Connected to my windows azure database using SSMS.  My database and all the tables show up within my object explorer.  But...this is where I'm scratching my head.  When I right click on a table, normally the option panel will have "Select all rows", "Edit all rows", ....etc.   but I don't see that.   I verified with a my ./SQLExpress instance I have all options.

Any advice?  Are there some SSMS settings that need updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure SQL Database doesn't support all of the options available via SSMS to SQL Server database users.  Sometimes it's because of network latency issues (Edit all rows...) and sometimes it's because certain features just aren't supported (like extended sp's).